# Cannot resolve symbol GetConnectionstring

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I have a .NET Core 3.0 class library. It is my first time working with .NET Core

I want to connect to a database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings shows **exactly** how to do it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 shows the method which exists in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace

I can't access it.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;  //no underlines and imported via Nuget

namespace Core.Cms.DAL
{
    public class Entities : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString.SqlServerExpress));

        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Why do I not have the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.GetConnectionString()` method available?

**edit**

Restarted rider - same issue

> Entities.cs(17, 45): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'GetConnectionString' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This might be just Intelisense error, try restart visual studio or clean build project

Comment: Restarted rider. Same issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `IConfiguration` interface. you can access to configuration form `DI` like this

```cs
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public Entities(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration
}
```

then use the `_configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString.SqlServerExpress)` instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.GetConnectionString()`

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString.SqlServerExpress));
```

if you are using the Asp.Net Core Web Application, This is a better way to config DbContext in **startup** class

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
```

```cs
services.AddDbContext<Entities>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString.SqlServerExpress));
});
```

**Update**

if you don't use the `DI` you can access to `IConfiguration` manually.

first you must install this packages

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`

then build the `IConfiguration`

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true,true)
   .Build();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString.SqlServerExpress));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.GetConnectionString` is an extension method on `IConfiguration`. So it cannot be ran statically like OP showed, but rather on the configuration object instance that implements `IConfiguration`

Comment: @rsobon why can't it be run. Is the example wrong? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings (last example before Feedback)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions my guess is that in the example they don't show that the `Configuration` is an instance held in private field, not a static class: `private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;`. It would be easier if they used resharper notation like `_configuration` instead of uppercase.

Comment: This is good but doesn't show what object I need to pass in... I'm not using DI in this project

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I updated my answer and you can access to `IConfiguration` without `DI`

Comment: Seems like I only needed `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Answer (score 28):

In .NET 6 you now use builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString like this

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
));
```

Comment: I have to remove the following method from ApplicationContext after adding the above lines in Program.cs

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

- First: using Some of The Namespaces in startup.cs File:

  1. using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
  2. using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
- Second: Write These Code inside Startup.cs file:

  1. Creating Property:

     ```
     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
     ```
  2. And This After Properties:

     ```
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
     }
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add below code connection string in .Net 6

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json, true, true").Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```